# Django Rest Framework: How to make UpdateAPIView to allow incremental updates

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have an array ("friends") such as below, that I want to be able to append to. I am using the regular UpdateAPIView but whenever I PUT/PATCH a new friend to the "friends" array, it overwrites the array completely with only the new friend.

```
{
        "friends": [
            {
                "first_name": "Bob" 
            },
            {
                "first_name": "Jon" 
            }

        ],
       "first_name": "User1", 
}
```

How can I use the UpdateAPIView to allow new items to be added to the array without re-POSTing the whole array. And also making sure that the friends list does not contain any duplicates?

**Models**

Im actually using MongoDB as my database but if you want to imagine im using mysql/postgres just ignore the fact im using MongoDB

```
class UserProfile(Document):
    db_id = IntField()
    email = EmailField()
    first_name = StringField()
    last_name = StringField()
    city = StringField()
    friends = ListField(ReferenceField('self'))
```

**Serializers**

```
class UserProfileSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    friends = PublicProfileSerializer(many=True, allow_add_remove=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        depth = 1
        exclude = ('db_id',)

  class PublicProfileSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'id')
```

Comment: Override the `update` method of your serializer and instead of replacing the friends list just append the new ones. If you show your model and serializer, I will help.

Comment: @norbertpy I updated the question with the model. If you were using mysql or similar what would your update method look like?

Comment: In the `friends` array, you are sending only the first name. This is not unique so you will have difficulty to add the relationship. Also, you will need a many-to-many field on User model. Is `ListField(ReferenceField('self'))` the same thing? I'm not familiar with MongoEngine.

Answer (score 0):

As @norbertpy mentioned in a comment, you can add an `update` method to the serializer to specify how you would like the update to be handled (in this case, making sure that incremental updates are made rather than overwriting existing data). This is documented [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances).

Here is an *example* of what the code may look like with the `update` method:

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    friends = PublicProfileSerializer(many=True, allow_add_remove=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        depth = 1
        exclude = ('db_id',)


class PublicProfileSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'id')

    def update(self, user_profile_instance, validated_friend_data):
        user_profile_instance.friends.extend(validated_friend_data)
        user_profile_instance.save()
        return user_profile_instance
```